# Tool for dumping Linux VFS superblock

Tags: linux, mount, vfs

From the `dumpe2fs` man page:

> `dumpe2fs` prints the super block and blocks group information for the filesystem present on device.

So `dumpe2fs` will dump the filesystem superblock. Is there any such tool to dump the Linux VFS superblock (i.e. in-memory superblock)?

Comment: What's your use case? What information do you specifically want to get from there?

Comment: The VFS superblock structure depends on which kind of a filesystem it points at. There are some general things common to all filesystems, but most of things in superblocks are not shared between, for example VFAT and EXT2.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I am trying to study how mount exactly works. During that I came across VFS `superblock`.

Comment: Then you're looking for kernel debugging tools like systemtap or kgdb to dump internal structures of the kernel. You'd be better of asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: `dumpe2fs` is probably not the command you want for that *unless* it is an `ext[234]` type filesystem. You probably want `wipefs` instead - it's a little more versatile.

Comment: @mikeserv `wipefs` is for `on-disk` filesystem. I am looking for a tool which can print VFS superblock (in-memory). But thanks for the command `wipefs`. I never heard about it before.

Comment: I understand that. I just meant that `wipefs` would be a more versatile tool than `dumpe2fs`. About the VFS thing - that I don't know, which is why I upvoted the question and only commented. I hope you do find an answer - I am curious. I think definitely Stéphane is onto something with debuggers though. It maybe `debugfs` could be a good direction to look?